# Java join duplicate methods

Tags: java, dry, code-duplication

I have two methods in service that are mostly the same, except for the entity and runnable type.

Is there a way to join them?

I think generics could be helpful but have no idea how to apply them here

```
public class PoliceService {
    private static final int API_REQUEST_PER_SEC = 15;
    private static final ExecutorService apiExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(API_REQUEST_PER_SEC); 

 public void downloadAllCrimesInDateRange(Map<String, String> map) {
        // Duplicate variables from map here

        List<Station> list = new ArrayList<>();
        CsvParser.getLinesFromCsvFile(file)
                 .forEach(strings -> list.add(new Station(strings[0], strings[2], strings[1])));

        for (int i = 0; i <= months; i++) {
            LinkedBlockingQueue<Station> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(list);

            for (int j = 0; j < queue.size(); j++) {
                apiExecutor.submit(new CrimeTask(queue.remove(),
                        from.plusMonths(i),
                        writeFile));
            }
        }
    }

    public void downloadStopAndSearch(Map<String, String> map) {
        // Duplicate variables from map here

        List<Force> list = new ArrayList<>();
        CsvParser.getLinesFromCsvFile(file)
                 .forEach(strings -> list.add(new Force(strings[0], strings[1])));

        for (int i = 0; i <= months; i++) {
            LinkedBlockingQueue<Force> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(list);
            
            for (int j = 0; j < queue.size(); j++) {
                apiExecutor.submit(new StopSearchTask(queue.remove(),
                        from.plusMonths(i),
                        writeFile));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the relationship between `Station` and `Force`?

Comment: @Simone Lungarella None. I can extend them from some `BaseEntity` if it may help

Comment: Same for `StopSearchTask` and `CrimeTask`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way I found to do it. If you really want to do it, this is a way but I don't really reccomend it.

You would end up having those methods:

```
public void downloadAllCrimesInDateRange(Map<String, String> map) {

    newMethod(map, TypeEnum.STATION);
}
   
public void downloadStopAndSearch(Map<String, String> map) {

    newMethod(map, TypeEnum.FORCE);
}
        
public void newMethod(Map<String, String> map, TypeEnum type) {

    List<BaseClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
    switch (type) {
    case FORCE:
        CsvParser.getLinesFromCsvFile(file)
                .forEach(strings -> list.add(new Force(strings[0], strings[1])));
        break;

    case STATION:
        CsvParser.getLinesFromCsvFile(file)
            .forEach(strings -> list.add(new Station(strings[0], strings[2], strings[1])));
        break;
    }
        

    for (int i = 0; i <= months; i++) {
        LinkedBlockingQueue<BaseClass> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(list);
            
        for (int j = 0; j < queue.size(); j++) {
            switch (type) {
            case FORCE:
                apiExecutor.submit(new StopSearchTask(queue.remove(),
                        from.plusMonths(i), writeFile));
                break;

            case STATION:
                apiExecutor.submit(new CrimeTask(queue.remove(),
                        from.plusMonths(i), writeFile));
                break;
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

This require to make a parent class for `StopSearchTask` and `CrimeTask`:

```
public class BaseTask { }
    
public class StopSearchTask extends BaseTask { }
    
public class CrimeTask extends BaseTask { }
```

And a parent class for `Force` and `Station` :

```
public class BaseClass { }
    
public class Station extends BaseClass { }
    
public class Force extends BaseClass { }
```

And an Enum to handle both type.

```
public static enum TypeEnum {
        STATION ,
        FORCE;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look great) Thanks for your effort anyway. I probably need to do some major refactoring